# pgsql on conflict (id) do update return "column reference "id" is ambiguous"

Tags: sql, postgresql, ambiguous

I have error.

"pq: column reference "id" is ambiguous"

I can solved the problem through add table name WHERE t.id = $1

But why I have "ambiguous"?

```
INSERT INTO t(id)
VALUES ($1)
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE
SET 
    id=10
WHERE id = $1
```

Comment: What keeps the statement from raising another `UNIQUE` violation for `id=10`? Actually guaranteed if you execute it more than once.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify whether the `where` clause is referring to the data *already in the table* or going in.  Presumably you intend:

```
INSERT INTO t(id)
    VALUES (7)
    ON CONFLICT (id)
    DO UPDATE SET id = 10
    WHERE excluded.id = 7;
```

Use `excluded` for the value already in the row (the row is "excluded" by the constraint).